# jQuery ajaxComplete called every time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a question regarding .ajaxComplete().

Lets say I do this:

```
// Register an ajaxComplete (pseudo code ish)
$('#someId').ajaxComplete(function () {
    if (ajaxCompleted == isAjaxImWaitingForToComplete) {
        // something something
    }
});
```

Then this will be called every time an ajax task finishes. Is there a way to make it only be called once, then unregister?
Could I add $('#someId').unbind(); at the bottom of the function inside the ajaxComplete?

Comment: No, but you could use a (correctly scoped) boolean variable that you set from false to true once you executed ajaxComplete() and check this variable first inside the ajaxComplete function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.ajaxComplete()` function binds a handler for the `ajaxComplete` [AJAX event](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events), so calling `.unbind('ajaxComplete');` should work.